# Auto-indenting graphviz .dot file

Tags: graphviz, dot, auto-indent

I am working on a long and complex architectural graph. The document indentation mixes tabs, spaces and indentation levels, which drives me crazy.

**Is there a simple way to automatically indent graphviz `.dot` files in Linux environment?**

A pure command line tool would be best, but plugins to popular editors like vim would be a good solution too.

**Update**:

The vim indentation has a bug with `:` in node names in edges. For example, `server_a:event -> log_server;` causes the next line to be further indented, presumably because the `:` is parsed as a block declaration (see comments on [Harry Pehkonen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20961629/51197)). Quoting the node name (e.g. `"server_a":event -> log_server;`) solves this issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re

dot=open('components.dot').read()
reg=re.compile("(\s)(\S+)(\:.*\-\>)")
print(reg.sub(r'\1"\2"\3', dot))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has dot syntax knowledge out of the box, and seems to re-indent dot files for me.

I removed all indentation, went to the top of the file, and did =G

Your global tab-related values determine whether to use tabs/spaces, how many, etc.

If you want, you can create a script with:

```
> vim -W reIndentAndSave whatever.dot
```

Edit your dot file by re-indenting from top with

```
gg=G
```

...Save

```
:x
```

Then, for each file you want to re-indent via the script that you just recorded,

```
> vim -s reIndentAndSave somegraph.dot
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that `:` in edges drive vim nuts. It treats them as new code blocks.

Comment: @AdamMatan I see what you mean.  I was able it to work by putting quotes around at least one of the nodes.  FAIL:  node0:port0 -> node1:port1;  SUCCEED:  "node0":port0 -> node1:port1;.  Still, it complicates any attempt at automating it :(

Comment: Not really - I can regex a solution for this. Will keep you updated. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my question with a Python code that fixes this issue, and accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On emacs, if the buffer has a mode that supports indentation, you can reindent a whole buffer like this: `C-x h` to select all buffer then `indent-region`.

It's interactive not scripted, but it works.

If your emacs that has `graphviz-dot-mode`, you can give it a try.

Yet I'm not fully satisfied by the result in this particular mode since it tends to not get closing braces aligned with opening braces (at least with `graphviz-dot-mode.el` Version 0.3.6 dates 19/02/2011).